# dragging points in matplotlib interactive plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created an interactive plot using `matplotlib` and following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46327978/1390639) answer.  The plot uses sliders in order to allow the user to control the vertical (y-axis) locations of the points and fits a spline to them as they are changed. The code to accomplish this is here:

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate as inter
import numpy as np



func = lambda x: 0.1*x**2

#get a list of points to fit a spline to as well
N = 10
xmin = 0
xmax = 10
x = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,N)

#spline fit
yvals = func(x)
spline = inter.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline (x, yvals)

#figure.subplot.right
mpl.rcParams['figure.subplot.right'] = 0.8

#set up a plot
fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(9.0,8.0),sharex=True)
ax1 = axes


interval = 100 # ms, time between animation frames
loop_len = 5.0 # seconds per loop
scale = interval / 1000 / loop_len

def update(val):
  # update curve
  for i in np.arange(N):
    yvals[i] = sliders[i].val
  l.set_ydata(yvals)
  spline = inter.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline (x, yvals)
  m.set_ydata(spline(X))
  # redraw canvas while idle
  fig.canvas.draw_idle()

X = np.arange(0,xmax+1,0.1)
ax1.plot (X, func(X), 'k--', label='original')
l, = ax1.plot (x,yvals,color='k',linestyle='none',marker='o',markersize=8)
m, = ax1.plot (X, spline(X), 'r-', label='spline')



ax1.set_yscale('linear')
ax1.set_xlim(0, xmax)
ax1.set_ylim(0,xmax)
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.yaxis.grid(True,which='minor',linestyle='--')
ax1.legend(loc=2,prop={'size':22})

sliders = []

for i in np.arange(N):

    axamp = plt.axes([0.84, 0.8-(i*0.05), 0.12, 0.02])
    # Slider
    s = Slider(axamp, 'p{0}'.format(i), 0, 10, valinit=yvals[i])
    sliders.append(s)


for i in np.arange(N):
    #samp.on_changed(update_slider)
    sliders[i].on_changed(update)


plt.show()
```

I think the user interface would be better if one could directly click on the points and drag them vertically upward or downward.  Which features of the `matplotlib` interactive code would be most helpful to do this?  I have looked at the various [widgets examples](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.1/examples/widgets/index.html), but have not found anything that is easy for me to see as directly useful for this.  The closest seems to be the [rectangle selector](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.1/examples/widgets/rectangle_selector.html), but I am unsure how to adapt it to get what I need.

EDIT:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43984357/1390639) answer can probably be adapted to do what I need.  The difference between this and exactly what I need is that the example picks a point (based on mouse click and drag) along an existing line and highlights it.  I need to click and select which existing point is within a small range (if none, then the dragging should do nothing).  Then the code should change that point as it is dragged and refit the spline during that dragging action.  I may be able to do this with the above example because it let me understand better how to use `mpl_connect` for different actions (and gave some example actions.

The final code should only allow dragging of points vertically, but I think that constraint will be easy to build in (i.e. only use y-coordinate of mouse click/release).

EDIT 2:

[The Poly Editor](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.2/gallery/event_handling/poly_editor.html?highlight=polygoninteractor) example seems to be very close to what I need, I can develop off of that.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [draggable-markers-in-matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982250/draggable-markers-in-matplotlib)? There is also the [Poly editor example](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.2/gallery/event_handling/poly_editor.html?highlight=polygoninteractor) on the matplotlib page. I think it would be good to know in how far those are or are not helping here, i.e. the problem should be specified more concretely.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, relying heavily on the [Poly Editor](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.2/gallery/event_handling/poly_editor.html?highlight=polygoninteractor) example, I have constructed an example that can either use the sliders to change the point values or click and drag the points.

The code is as follows, with diagnostic prints commented:

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate as inter
import numpy as np



func = lambda x: 0.1*x**2

#get a list of points to fit a spline to as well
N = 10
xmin = 0 
xmax = 10 
x = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,N)

#spline fit
yvals = func(x)
spline = inter.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline (x, yvals)

#figure.subplot.right
mpl.rcParams['figure.subplot.right'] = 0.8

#set up a plot
fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(9.0,8.0),sharex=True)
ax1 = axes


pind = None #active point
epsilon = 5 #max pixel distance

def update(val):
    global yvals
    global spline
    # update curve
    for i in np.arange(N):
      yvals[i] = sliders[i].val 
    l.set_ydata(yvals)
    spline = inter.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline (x, yvals)
    m.set_ydata(spline(X))
    # redraw canvas while idle
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

def reset(event):
    global yvals
    global spline
    #reset the values
    yvals = func(x)
    for i in np.arange(N):
      sliders[i].reset()
    spline = inter.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline (x, yvals)
    l.set_ydata(yvals)
    m.set_ydata(spline(X))
    # redraw canvas while idle
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

def button_press_callback(event):
    'whenever a mouse button is pressed'
    global pind
    if event.inaxes is None:
        return
    if event.button != 1:
        return
    #print(pind)
    pind = get_ind_under_point(event)    

def button_release_callback(event):
    'whenever a mouse button is released'
    global pind
    if event.button != 1:
        return
    pind = None

def get_ind_under_point(event):
    'get the index of the vertex under point if within epsilon tolerance'

    # display coords
    #print('display x is: {0}; display y is: {1}'.format(event.x,event.y))
    t = ax1.transData.inverted()
    tinv = ax1.transData 
    xy = t.transform([event.x,event.y])
    #print('data x is: {0}; data y is: {1}'.format(xy[0],xy[1]))
    xr = np.reshape(x,(np.shape(x)[0],1))
    yr = np.reshape(yvals,(np.shape(yvals)[0],1))
    xy_vals = np.append(xr,yr,1)
    xyt = tinv.transform(xy_vals)
    xt, yt = xyt[:, 0], xyt[:, 1]
    d = np.hypot(xt - event.x, yt - event.y)
    indseq, = np.nonzero(d == d.min())
    ind = indseq[0]

    #print(d[ind])
    if d[ind] >= epsilon:
        ind = None
    
    #print(ind)
    return ind

def motion_notify_callback(event):
    'on mouse movement'
    global yvals
    if pind is None:
        return
    if event.inaxes is None:
        return
    if event.button != 1:
        return
    
    #update yvals
    #print('motion x: {0}; y: {1}'.format(event.xdata,event.ydata))
    yvals[pind] = event.ydata 

    # update curve via sliders and draw
    sliders[pind].set_val(yvals[pind])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

X = np.arange(0,xmax+1,0.1)
ax1.plot (X, func(X), 'k--', label='original')
l, = ax1.plot (x,yvals,color='k',linestyle='none',marker='o',markersize=8)
m, = ax1.plot (X, spline(X), 'r-', label='spline')



ax1.set_yscale('linear')
ax1.set_xlim(0, xmax)
ax1.set_ylim(0,xmax)
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.yaxis.grid(True,which='minor',linestyle='--')
ax1.legend(loc=2,prop={'size':22})

sliders = []

for i in np.arange(N):

    axamp = plt.axes([0.84, 0.8-(i*0.05), 0.12, 0.02])
    # Slider
    s = Slider(axamp, 'p{0}'.format(i), 0, 10, valinit=yvals[i])
    sliders.append(s)

    
for i in np.arange(N):
    #samp.on_changed(update_slider)
    sliders[i].on_changed(update)

axres = plt.axes([0.84, 0.8-((N)*0.05), 0.12, 0.02])
bres = Button(axres, 'Reset')
bres.on_clicked(reset)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', button_press_callback)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', button_release_callback)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', motion_notify_callback)

plt.show()
```

I did not encapsulate the code into an object as the [Poly Editor](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.2/gallery/event_handling/poly_editor.html?highlight=polygoninteractor) example did, but that should be an upgrade that is easy to do.

[image]

Comment: Great answer! With a good deal of modification I used it in my application, it was a good starting point.
if someone else uses it in the future, I give a little warning: The update of the graph is tangled with the update of the sliders, u should decouple them in case your use case doesn't use sliders.