# Drag a "bar" through a graph and present values in a textbox?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I started with python yesterday and so far I have made a graph in which uses 4 columns of data from a .txt file. Everything is working great. Now what I would like to have is a dragable bar or something like that.
That you can drag through the graph and get the values from y, y1 and y2 at any given time (which is the X-value) presented in a textbox or something in that matter.
Problem is, I don't even now what to search for to begin exploring alternatives.

Using matplotlib and numpy.

Code here.

```
import numpy  as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
data = np.loadtxt('test.txt')

x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
y2 = data[:, 2]
y3 = data[:, 3]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,5))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x, y, '--', label='Voltage')
ax.plot(x, y2, '-.', label='Current')


ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, y3,'g:', label='Temperature')

fig.legend(edgecolor = ("DarkBlue"), facecolor = ("LightBlue"), loc="upper right", bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)

ax.set_title("Test Surveillance", color = ("Purple"))    
ax.set_xlabel('Milliseconds', color = ("LightGreen"))
ax.set_ylabel('Volts and Amps', color = ("DarkGrey"))
ax2.set_ylabel('Celsius', color = ("LightBlue"))
ax2.set_ylim(18, 100)

plt.xlim(0)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439506/dragging-points-in-matplotlib-interactive-plot

Comment: [Plotly Express](https://plotly.com/python/animations/) might also be able to do the job, except rather than the data being presented via a hover box