# Moving Data of Scatter Plot Graph manually

Tags: python, scatter-plot, plotly-dash

I'm building a dashboard using Dash in Python . My requirement is to plot a Scatter plot with values and move those values manually up and down which will perform a call back based on the new value the dot is moved inside the scatter plot.

My question is there a way to move the dots inside the scatter plot ? I read through internet and I was not able to find any solution . However I can see hovering/clicking the dots that does a call back but was not moved. Can anyone help me with this question.

Thanks,
Prathap

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439506/dragging-points-in-matplotlib-interactive-plot

Comment: But I'm using Pydash to build the dashboard . So Similarly after plotting the scatter plot I want to move the points inside the graph to new values which will do a call back and update other graph. Callback is ok but I want to move the points inside the plot. Any suggestions?